# Nominal and non-dichotomous variables

Tags: chi-squared-test, ordinal-data, fishers-exact-test

I am having problems analysing baseline data for my study population.

My variables are erection dysfunction severity (mild, moderate and severe) and type of erection dysfunction (organic ED and psychogenic ED).

I want to know the percentage of mild, moderate and severe ED in both groups (organic and psychogenic) and whether the difference is significant.

Since the erection severity variable is non-dichotomous I cannot use chi square and Fisher's exact test.
Please advise me which test I can use.

Comment: Your assertions (that you cannot use chi-square and Fisher's exact test) are incorrect. However, the ordering suggests other possibilities, depending on the precise alternatives of interest (which are unstated)

Comment: Glen_b thanks for the swift reply. I said I cannot use chi square test because the variable ED severity has 3 levels ( mild, moderate and severe), this violates dichotomous rule of chi square. Please correct me if I am wrong on this.

Comment: I want to know the distribution of ED severity i.e mild, moderate and severe ED in the two groups (organic and psychogenic ED ) and whether the distribution is significant .

Comment: 1. You can have 20 categories on one and 35 on the other if you want; there's no requirement that chi-square or Fisher exact test be limited to 2x2. If you have a textbook or something that says otherwise it would be incorrect. 2. You can estimate the distribution from the sample proportions; if you have the contingency table you don't really need computers for that (though it's sometimes convenient). ... ctd

Comment: ctd... 3. It's not at all clear what you intend by "whether the distribution is significant". What are you trying to find out about the distribution? *Without* using any statistical terms (like significant), what's the scientific question here? (I can make a guess, but it's best if you identify your own working hypotheses; this will help figure out whether you need something that considers the ordering)

Comment: Thanks alot. Your answers are very helpful, now everything makes sense. I meant whether there is significant difference between the two variables. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for *any* kind of difference in distribution rather than just a shift up or down, a chi-squared test should be fine. It doesn't matter that the dimension is larger than 2x2.

Similarly a Fisher Exact test may be done on tables larger than 2x2.

If you're specifically interested in a tendency to higher (or lower) categories on the ordered variable, you would want to consider different tests with better power against such alternatives.

Here's examples of a chi=squared and Fisher exact test done on a 2x3 table in R:

```
> table(ED)
          type
severity   organic psychogenic
  mild          24          15
  moderate      15          15
  severe        10          21

> chisq.test(table(ED))

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  table(ED)
X-squared = 5.9425, df = 2, p-value = 0.05124


> fisher.test(table(ED))

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  table(ED)
p-value = 0.05536
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```